# Custom keyboard on IOS with buttons displaying images

Tags: ios, swift, ipad, custom-keyboard

I have the below code that runs on iPad successfully.

```
func setupLockPinSection() {

        let keys = ["1", "2","3", "4","5", "6","7", "8","9", "0", "Clear", "Done"]
        let kbFrame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: view.frame.width, height: 400)

        if let customKeyboard = Bundle.main.loadNibNamed("MACustomKeyboard", owner: self, options: nil)?.first as? MACustomKeyboard {

            customKeyboard.frame = kbFrame
            customKeyboard.setKeyboardButtons(keys)

            lockPin1.inputView = customKeyboard

            //Number Tapped
            customKeyboard.numberTappedBlock = { [weak self] view, text in

                if let textFieldText = self?.lockPin1.text, let t = text {
                    self?.lockPin1.text = textFieldText + t
                }

            }

            //Done button Tapped
            customKeyboard.doneTappedBlock = { [weak self] view in
                self?.lockPin1.resignFirstResponder()
            }

            //Clear Button Tapped
            customKeyboard.clearTappedBlock = { [weak self] view in

                if let text = self?.lockPin1.text, text.characters.count > 0 {
                    self?.lockPin1.text = text.substring(to: text.index(text.endIndex, offsetBy: -1))
                }

            }

        }

        if let customKeyboard = Bundle.main.loadNibNamed("MACustomKeyboard", owner: self, options: nil)?.first as? MACustomKeyboard {

            customKeyboard.frame = kbFrame
            customKeyboard.setKeyboardButtons(keys)

            lockPin2.inputView = customKeyboard

            //Number Tapped
            customKeyboard.numberTappedBlock = { [weak self] view, text in

                if let textFieldText = self?.lockPin2.text, let t = text {
                    self?.lockPin2.text = textFieldText + t
                }

            }

            //Done button Tapped
            customKeyboard.doneTappedBlock = { [weak self] view in
                self?.lockPin2.resignFirstResponder()
            }

            //Clear Button Tapped
            customKeyboard.clearTappedBlock = { [weak self] view in

                if let text = self?.lockPin2.text, text.characters.count > 0 {
                    self?.lockPin2.text = text.substring(to: text.index(text.endIndex, offsetBy: -1))
                }

            }

        }

        lockPin1.text = UserDefaults.standard.string(forKey: "lockPin")
        lockPin2.text = UserDefaults.standard.string(forKey: "lockPin")

    }
```

I want to make the clear and done button like the ones on iOS default keyboard with the displaying images (hiding keyboard button, clear button). I want to do this because, for my lock pin functionality I just want to use digits, and on iPad it does not allow that. Hence I need to make it customized keyboard.

Comment: So what's your problem? :)

Comment: @d4Rk, I just posted by problem below in more details with images. If you could please give it a look and propose me a solution. Appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

[This is what I have now with the above code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b8OUo.png)

[The keyboard down button (button on the low right corner) and the clear button (button on the top right corner), I want to implement them in my custom keyboard so I have them instead of my "clear" and "done" buttons](https://i.stack.imgur.com/17Xr7.png)

This is what I want to accomplish!

Comment: Write this in your question. It is not an answer.